# About google crawling php pages

Tags: php, google-crawlers

I have a website , php based. I am wondering if google crawls php sites with same header but differet content.

http://www.nyitforums.com/professors/browse_all_prof.php?bdepartment=0

Each "view" button returns the same html template but with different results, So does google crawl all of them? If not, how can I do this?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign up to Google Webmaster Tools: http://www.google.com/webmasters/
So you will know better what Google is crawling on your website.